# Google maps GroundOverlay's image dimensions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsgroundoverlay

I cannot find any resource for the standard dimensions of GroundOverlay images (e.g. pixels per meter). How should I calculate it in a way it is efficient but doesn't compromise the quality?

Comment: I think you can just Set the `icon property` to an instance of `UIImage`. Here are the steps:1. Instantiate a new GMSGroundOverlay object
2. Set the icon property to an instance of UIImage.
3. Set the bounds property to an instance of GMSCoordinateBounds. The bounds represent the south west, and north east corners of the image.
4.Set optional properties, such as bearing and zoomLevel, as desired.
5. Set the map property - the image appears on the map. For more details, please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/overlays).

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I am asking for. I was asking for sizes (in pixels) of the images to be used.